# PyQgis on stand-alone Python software says ImportError: No module named qgis.core?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I'm quite new to Python, but I learned the basics with ArcPy in the Python software IDLE. It was quite easy to getting started: I start my script with "import arcpy" and i could start coding with arcpy functions.

But I'd like to work with QGis and PyQgis now. And I cannot make it work. When I start my script with "from qgis.core import *", i get an error message saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    from qgis.core import *
ImportError: No module named qgis.core
```

I guess that I have to make a liaison between Python and the Qgis module somehow, it is probably very basic but I can't find the answer.

How do I set-up my python so it can use the qgis functions?

Comment: Seems to be a common error message: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%22No%20module%20named%20qgis.core%22

Comment: It is, but I don't find a clear answer to solve my problem.

Comment: PyQgis is hard to understand after using ArcPy. You have to install different IDE (for example PyCharm and setup correctly to use it using). See: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2018/02/13/quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis3-on-windows/ for more info.

Comment: Thank you, this is the kind of resource that I was looking for, I'm going to try this.

Comment: @JBihin Link updated (for QGIS 3.0) Skip `pb_tool` installation.

Comment: There is still some elements that I don't get. For instance, why do I have to do all of this, I'm trying to understand but all this page do is telling me to copy-paste some stuff and to install some package but I'm not sure why. (I like to understand what I'm doing)

It still does not work but I'm going to keep working on it tomorrow and try.

Comment: If you have QGIS installed and if it works fine, then you don't have to install any extra packages. The only thing you have to do is to set the `PYTHONPATH`, so when you run the script, your console knows where to find the `qgis.core`. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html here is the link on how to set the `PYTHONPATH`(look at the end of the page).